# submit form after validation pass

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to run validation to all necessary fields and if no errors found submit form.

**My script:**

```
function validate() {
  var var1 = document.getElementById("advertisement_age"),
    var2 = document.getElementById("advertisement_weight"),
    var3 = document.getElementById("advertisement_region_id"),
    var4 = document.getElementById("advertisement_height");


judge.validate(var1,var2,var3,var4), {

  valid: function(element) {
    element.style.border = '1px solid green';
  },
  invalid: function(element, messages) {
    element.style.border = '1px solid red';
    alert(messages.join(','));
  }
// After no errors I want to submit form.
  $('#advertisement_registration_form').submit();
});
```

But in Mozzila Firebug I got multiple errors:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
$('#advertisement_registration_form').submit();
```

I can't figure out what is causing this problem.

Thanks

Comment: `$('#advertisement_registration_form').submit();` should be in the `valid` function, not halfway in an object declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the `)` after `var4` and `$('#advertisement_registration_form').submit();` should be after the function call.

```
function validate() {
  var var1 = document.getElementById("advertisement_age"),
    var2 = document.getElementById("advertisement_weight"),
    var3 = document.getElementById("advertisement_region_id"),
    var4 = document.getElementById("advertisement_height");


  judge.validate(var1,var2,var3,var4, {

    valid: function(element) {
      element.style.border = '1px solid green';
    },
    invalid: function(element, messages) {
      element.style.border = '1px solid red';
      alert(messages.join(','));
    }
  });

  // After no errors I want to submit form.
  $('#advertisement_registration_form').submit();
}
```

Comment: Tnx, but now script validates just last element, not all 4.

Comment: Not working. Now gives some syntax error. It validetas just last element.

Comment: Can this function validate multiple elements at once? If not, you will have to call it for each element separately.

Comment: Each element have different validation rule. I guess it means I  need to do it seperately.. But how I can create script that first of all checks all validations and then submits form?

Comment: You put the elements in an array, iterate over it and call the validate function for each. If all of them pass you submit the form.